# C# Programmatically perform click event on the custom context menu item in outlook on a mail

Tags: c#, outlook, contextmenu, outlook-addin

I have developed outlook Add-in which basically have to take the mail item from sent items (on click of a button on the ribbon) and programmatically click on context menu item "My custom button". It is mainly task of adding the mail into some store. I tried lot to trigger the menu item but not able to perform. Is there any way that i can pick the mail and perform click event directly on my menu item or i have to basically perform the mouse right Click event and then try to click the custom menu item. Hoping for the great solution.

Comment: Where does that context menu come from? Is it implemented by some other addin?

Comment: Already context menu is there. if we  right click on mail item we find some context menu items..I want to trigger one among them that is "My custom Button" but i don't want to do it manually It has to be done programmatically in C#.

Comment: Again, what creates that context menu item? Is it a built-in item? Created by some other addin? Created by your own addin?

Comment: It is created by  some other add in. I want to invoke that menu item in my outlook add in.